# How to export the SpreadSheet data in Paraview while collecting data

Tags: paraview

I’m using Paraview to view some data. I can see information in the spreadsheet and I want to use the Python API to output this data to the terminal. I think I have to use FindView() to get into the spreadsheet. How can I print out this data to the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the use case of ParaView. ParaView is a high level tool and is intended to manipulate the filters, the readers and their properties to create visualization. But not the data itself.

That is why it is not so easy.

You can get some meta-data (nb of values, min, max and so):
https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/understandingData.html#getting-data-information-in-pvpython

If you still need the actual data array, see the `servermanager.Fetch` method: https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/latest/python/paraview.servermanager.html#paraview.servermanager.Fetch